# List and call js functions from a newly loaded tab from firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am interested in scanning a new opened tab's content for any javascript functions that are on the page, and being able to call them. What is the proper way to do this?

I have a handle to the tab, because I am using

```
tabs.on('ready, function (tab) {
    var functionNames = [];
    for (var f in tab) {
        if(tab.hasOwnProperty(f) && typeof tab[f] === 'function') { functionNames.push(f);
        }
    }
console.log(functionNames);
}
```

However, this gives me an error that `tab` does not have `hasOwnProperty`

I have tried to change it to `this` and `window` as well and neither have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a sandbox allows you to tap in and see everything on the window object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.Sandbox#Executing_in_current_tab_scope

Comment: Well, I started to dig into this, but as I was, I found the tabs/content scripts method. Essentially this let me execute in an unsafeWindow. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts

Comment: Do you have any comments as to the validity of the method I found? It seems like about every time I get back into FF extension developing, there are new methods for accomplishing everything compared to what I used to know!

Comment: Hey @Derek yep contentScript is exactly the same thing, except you don't have to worry about the sandbox creation stuff. That is the addon-sdk, sadnbox is for non-sdk.

Comment: Cool thanks - I was using addon-sdk (which didnt exist back when i first started FF extension development). Still trying to re-adjust.